# How to extract information from the cell of a variable and put it inside duplicated row?

Tags: string, python-3.x, pandas, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have a data set with `'UserID'`, system that is used by user `'System'` and concatenation of those two. Here is an example of the [data set](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kvyynzjr9a22908/RolCatBR_IDMqes1.xlsx?dl=0):

`RolCatBR_IDMqes1.loc[0:15]`

```
UserID            System         CONCAT A
0   ANTANAS  P1B_010, P2Z_010  P1B_010|ANTANAS
1   AWYGASC  P1B_010, P2Z_010  P1B_010|AWYGASC
2   CHENQIA  P1B_010, P2Z_010  P1B_010|CHENQIA
3   CHENQIA  P3Z_020, P3Z_030  P3Z_020|CHENQIA
4   DBORZUT  P1B_010, P2Z_010  P1B_010|DBORZUT
5   DURAKER  P1B_010, P2Z_010  P1B_010|DURAKER
6   JEBINDE  P1B_010, P2Z_010  P1B_010|JEBINDE
7   SMETTAN  P1B_010, P2Z_010  P1B_010|SMETTAN
8   TKAUL13  P3Z_020, P3Z_030  P3Z_020|TKAUL13
9   VATERCH  P3Z_020, P3Z_030  P3Z_020|VATERCH
10  ABUNNEN           P2Z_010  P2Z_010|ABUNNEN
11  AMILSKI           P2Z_010  P2Z_010|AMILSKI
12  ANMUE24           P2Z_010  P2Z_010|ANMUE24
13  BKAEPPL           P2Z_010  P2Z_010|BKAEPPL
14  BRUDERA           P2Z_010  P2Z_010|BRUDERA
15  CHRROMM           P2Z_010  P2Z_010|CHRROMM
```

For example: the first row `[0]`, I need to take out the second system - `P2Z_010`, create the new row with the same `UserID`and put the system information- `P2Z_010` with updated `CONCAT A`.

```
     UserID   System         CONCAT A
0     ANTANAS  P1B_010    P1B_010|ANTANAS
0.5   ANTANAS  P2Z_010    P2Z_010|ANTANAS
1     AWYGASC  P1B_010    P1B_010|AWYGASC
1.5   AWYGASC  P2Z_010    P2Z_010|AWYGASC
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so called unnesting , I am using `str.split` and `str.len` with `repeat`

```
s=df['System'].str.split(',')
pd.DataFrame({'UserID':df.UserID.repeat(s.str.len()),'System':sum(s.tolist(),[]),'CONCATA':df.CONCATA.repeat(s.str.len())})
Out[531]: 
            CONCATA   System   UserID
0   P1B_010|ANTANAS  P1B_010  ANTANAS
0   P1B_010|ANTANAS  P2Z_010  ANTANAS
1   P1B_010|AWYGASC  P1B_010  AWYGASC
1   P1B_010|AWYGASC  P2Z_010  AWYGASC
2   P1B_010|CHENQIA  P1B_010  CHENQIA
2   P1B_010|CHENQIA  P2Z_010  CHENQIA
3   P3Z_020|CHENQIA  P3Z_020  CHENQIA
3   P3Z_020|CHENQIA  P3Z_030  CHENQIA
4   P1B_010|DBORZUT  P1B_010  DBORZUT
4   P1B_010|DBORZUT  P2Z_010  DBORZUT
5   P1B_010|DURAKER  P1B_010  DURAKER
5   P1B_010|DURAKER  P2Z_010  DURAKER
6   P1B_010|JEBINDE  P1B_010  JEBINDE
6   P1B_010|JEBINDE  P2Z_010  JEBINDE
7   P1B_010|SMETTAN  P1B_010  SMETTAN
7   P1B_010|SMETTAN  P2Z_010  SMETTAN
8   P3Z_020|TKAUL13  P3Z_020  TKAUL13
8   P3Z_020|TKAUL13  P3Z_030  TKAUL13
9   P3Z_020|VATERCH  P3Z_020  VATERCH
9   P3Z_020|VATERCH  P3Z_030  VATERCH
10  P2Z_010|ABUNNEN  P2Z_010  ABUNNEN
11  P2Z_010|AMILSKI  P2Z_010  AMILSKI
12  P2Z_010|ANMUE24  P2Z_010  ANMUE24
13  P2Z_010|BKAEPPL  P2Z_010  BKAEPPL
14  P2Z_010|BRUDERA  P2Z_010  BRUDERA
15  P2Z_010|CHRROMM  P2Z_010  CHRROMM
```

Comment: What if I have a lot of other columns in the data set according to this example I have to put them similar as you did for UserID variable: `'UserID':df.UserID.repeat(s.str.len())`, right? Could you explain me please what does the code inside the `repeat` for `UserID` and `CONCATA`?

Comment: @user21 repeat the same user by the length of system , so we can unnest ths data frame

Comment: I could not execute this part of code `sum(s.tolist(),[])` because `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list`. What should I do?

Comment: @user21 change to `np.concatenate(s.values)`

Comment: if I do this then the Value error appears: `ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions`.

Comment: The reason for the mistake is `NaN` values for `UserID` and `System` columns. I guess if I delete rows with `NaN`, the code should work.